# Can't seem to configure Tailwind CSS 2 on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I'm trying to install Tailwind CSS in a RoR 6.0.3 Ruby 3.0.0 project, but cannot seem to have it work. I don't get any error messages, but I'm just not seeing any update to the styling in the output on localhost.

ANy guidance, much appreciated.

**tailwind.config.js**

```
...
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
  ],
...
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss')('./app/javascript/css/tailwind.js'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009'
      },
      stage: 3
    })
  ]
}
```

**javascript/stylesheets/application.scss**

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

**application.html.erb**

```
  <head>
    <title>Photos</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
```

**javascript/packs/application.js**

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("stylesheets/application.scss")
```

**views/home/index.html.erb**

```
<h1 class="animate-pulse font-bold text-gray-200 text-2xl mb-6">Photos</h1>
```

Comment: I had to follow the PostCSS 7 installation guide to get Tailwind 2 working with Rails https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build

If it's not that, then you might want to check this line `('./app/javascript/css/tailwind.js')` is pointing to the correct file.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction:

`('./app/javascript/css/tailwind.js'),` should have been:

`('./app/javascript/css/tailwind.config.js'),`